# what would be most correct here?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I want to know what is most correct:

I fell on the snow

I fell in the snow

Context: someone falls and there's snow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snow normally sinks down when you fall; that's clearly correct.

Google NGrams agrees:

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fall+on+the+snow%2C+fall+in+the+snow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfall%20on%20the%20snow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfall%20in%20the%20snow%3B%2Cc0

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+fell+on+the+snow%2C+I+fell+in+the+snow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20fell%20in%20the%20snow%3B%2Cc0

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fell+on+the+snow%2C+fell+in+the+snow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfell%20on%20the%20snow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfell%20in%20the%20snow%3B%2Cc0

Either can technically be used, but unless you're a feather, you're sinking into the snow, so it would be more correct to say "I fell in the snow".

Comment: No problem! Though it occurs to me now that if the snow was hard or icy, "on" would be preferable. I was thinking of powder when I wrote this: it is in fact contingent on the type of snow, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You fall in the snow! - As you cannot fall on the snow and remain above it!
So it is: I fell in the snow!